# SocketCAN in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socketcan

I use ARM board with embedded Linux on it, but it is very limited. Somehow I managed to install node.js and npm. The idea is to send data via CAN bus on button click event from the web page. I have found only one module called "socketcan", but I cannot install it due to following lines:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
node-gyp configure && node-gyp build
```

My board fails to execute the first line, that means I can't use the only found CAN tool for node.js.
Is there any other possibility to read and write messages on CAN bus from node.js?

Answer (score 2):

Socketcan doesn't work on the lattest Nodejs. I've got the same problem. Just install a Node.js version 0.10.x. For the arm7 you can get it from this page :

[Conor O'Neills Page: http://conoroneill.net/](http://conoroneill.net/node-v01040-and-v0127-for-arm-v7-raspberry-pi-2-banana-pi-odroid-c1-available/)

Thanks to Conor O'Neill you can download it on his Page and install socketcan without getting any errors. At the moment, I am struggeling how socketcan works in express-generate. So if someone has clue. I would appreciate it.

Comment: According to this posts [link](https://github.com/sebi2k1/node-can/issues/7)  it should now working on Node 4.1

Comment: Thanks to @AnnaBanana I managed to install node-gyp on my board, but to install socketcan I need to rebuild node-gyp and this process requires "make", which I don't have due to limited Linux version

Comment: If you use "npm install socketcan" it will build it by himself and you don't need to execute these lines by yourself anymore.

Comment: That's correct, during install socketcan will try to rebuild node-gyp automatically. But then node-gyp will require "make", which I don't have in my limited embedded Linux